SeleniumBase UC can't resolve captcha in Docker but work in local
I’m using SeleniumBase with Undetected ChromeDriver (UC) to bypass captchas. The script works perfectly on my macOS (local machine) using Chrome. However, when I run the same code inside a Docker container based on the official SeleniumBase image, it fails to bypass the captcha.
Here’s the code I’m using:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(headed=True, uc=True, test=True, undetectable=True) as sb:
    url = "https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in"
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    print(sb.uc_gui_click_captcha())  # Debug log
    sb.assert_text("Username", '[for="user_login"]', timeout=3)
    sb.assert_element('label[for="user_login"]')
    sb.highlight('button:contains("Sign in")')
    sb.highlight('h1:contains("GitLab.com")')
    sb.post_message("SeleniumBase wasn't detected", duration=4)

What I’ve Tried:
1. Running locally:
Works fine, captcha is bypassed.
2. Running in Docker:
Used headed=True and X11 to view the browser -> Browser opens, but captcha resolution fails.
Question:  Why does the captcha bypass fail in Docker? Do I need extra configuration for UC in the container or something else please ?
Thank you for reading my question, any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I also tried in a Windows VM (in AWS), but I encountered the same problem, if anybody can help me

According to @MichaelMintz, Docker can't work, I don't know the problem for my Windows EC2 instance (Comments section)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr90iQmNsKM
